# Logic to get filter a list in C# or by stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recursion

Suppose I have following data in my table, where an `Item` has a parent ID 0. But there could only be three sub-levels/children of a parent. That is we need each item that has parentId = 0, and each parent can have up to three levels of children.

```
pkProductID       Name            ParentId 
-------------------------------------------
1                 Cloth              0
2                 T-Shirts           1
3                 Men-Shirts         2
4                 Women-Shirts       2
5                 Kids-Shirts        3
6                 Cosmetics          0
7                 Creams             6
8                 Men-cream          7
9                 Women-Cream        7
10                Kids-cream         9
```

We need list that contains items that has `parentID=0` and then 2 levels of that children that means from above I need only these items:

```
1 Cloth
2 T-Shirts
3 Men-Shirts
4 Women-Shirts
6 Cosmetics
7 Creams
8 Men-Cream
9 Women-Cream
```

Comment: You can use a [recursion](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-recursion-in-stored-procedures/5700193) within your stored-procedure.

Comment: Needed some specific details. Please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the work (change `table` or `columns` names accordingly):

```
use [DemoDB]
GO
WITH Emp_CTE AS (
SELECT ProductId, Name, ParentID, 0 as [Level]
FROM [dbo].[Products]
WHERE ParentId = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Name, p.ParentID, [Level] + 1
FROM [dbo].[Products] as p
INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.ProductId = p.ParentID
WHERE [Level] < 2
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT [dbo].[Products].*
    FROM Emp_CTE
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] ON Emp_CTE.ProductId = [dbo].[Products].ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2

GO
```

Comment: How does this solution make sure you only get up to 2 levels of children?

Comment: @marc_s Good point, he should hold a variable in order to count the level depth.

Comment: @marc_s I changed my code so it will be able to control the depth level of the recursion.

Comment: This is Great and it worked for this me but difficult to understand.

Comment: The Coloum ProductId was specified multiple times for 'CTE2'.. The above throws this error while executing. This is how I used your query. Please tell me where I am wrong, While it is working fine if I do not include CTE2

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_YourPractise
AS
BEGIN
with Emp_CTE as(
 select pkProductID,productName,ParentID, 0 as [Level] from products where parentId=0 union ALL 
    SELECT p.pkProductID,p.productName,p.ParentID, [Level] + 1 from products as p
    inner join Emp_CTE ecte   on  ecte.pkProductID=p.ParentID
where [Level] <2
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Emp_CTE
       INNER JOIN products ON Emp_CTE.pkProductID = products.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2
    
END

Comment: This query works for me @Yair                                   ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_YourPractise
AS
BEGIN
with Emp_CTE as(
 select pkProductID,productName,ParentID, 0 as [Level] from products where parentId=0 union ALL 
    SELECT p.pkProductID,p.productName,p.ParentID, [Level] + 1 from products as p
    inner join Emp_CTE ecte   on  ecte.pkProductID=p.ParentID
where [Level] <2
)


    SELECT *
    FROM Emp_CTE


    
END

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this type of task, take a look at this link here that shows a simple example: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/ and there's another example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

```
CREATE TABLE #clothes(
pkProductID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(50),
ParentId INT
)


INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 1, 'cloth', 0 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 2, 'tshirt', 1 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 3, 'mens tshirt', 2 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 4, 'womens tshirt', 2 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 5, 'kids tshirt', 3 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 6, 'cosme', 0 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 7, 'cream', 6 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 8, 'm cream', 7 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 9, 'w cream', 7 )

INSERT  INTO #clothes
        ( pkProductID, NAME, ParentId )
VALUES  ( 10, 'kids cream', 9 )

WITH myCTE AS (
SELECT pkProductID ,
        NAME ,
        ParentId, 0 AS ItemLevel FROM #clothes
        WHERE ParentId = 0

UNION all
SELECT c.pkProductID ,
        c.NAME ,
        c.ParentId, ItemLevel + 1 FROM #clothes c INNER JOIN myCTE mc ON mc.pkProductID = c.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM   myCTE WHERE ItemLevel <=2 ORDER BY pkProductID
```

Comment: How does this solution make sure you only get up to 2 levels of children?

Comment: @marc_s, missed that part - my bad!

Comment: Latest One           ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_YourPractise]
AS
BEGIN
with Emp_CTE as(
 select pkProductID,productName,ParentID, 0 as [Level] from products where parentId=0 union ALL 
    SELECT p.pkProductID,p.productName,p.ParentID, [Level] + 1 from products as p
    inner join Emp_CTE ecte   on  ecte.pkProductID=p.ParentID
where [Level] <2
)
--,
--CTE2 AS
--(
    SELECT *
    FROM Emp_CTE
   --    INNER JOIN products ON Emp_CTE.pkProductID = product.ParentID
--)
--SELECT * FROM CTE2
    
END